# Trying to show JFrame in AWT thread before while

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, awt

I have in my code the following method:

```
public String a(){
    String answer = null;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(150, 150, 600, 600);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.red);
    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            answer = "answer";
        }
    });
    p.add(button);
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    while(answer == null){
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

When I call this method from the main thread, everything shows normally, and the method works. But when I call it from the `AWT_Thread` the frame comes out completely blank.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: BTW - it looks like that entire frame would best be replaced with `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)`

Comment: Swing is Single Threaded, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details